# In manim, how to change axis number font color

Tags: python, manim

I'm trying to change the font color of Manim GraphScene axes. However, when I initialize `GraphScene` init function with:

```py
class ExampleProba(GraphScene):
    def __init__(self):
        GraphScene.__init__(
            self,
            axes_color=BLACK,
        )
```

I actually only get the axes to be BLACK but not the numbers below it. Any idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, you need to actually change the `decimal_number_config` just like this

```py
class ExampleProba(GraphScene):
    def __init__(self):
        GraphScene.__init__(
            self,
            y_axis_config={"decimal_number_config": {"num_decimal_places":2, "color":BLACK}},
            y_axis_config={"decimal_number_config": {"color":BLACK}}
        )
```